# Medjool Dates (bugs?)

Tags: kashrut-kosher, bugs, fruits

We have a 2 lbs box of medjool dates. Very fancy. But it has been on the shelf for about 2 months. At first, when we split it, no visible bugs. Now we are seeing small white spots near the seed, salt grain sized.

Even with a good magnifying glass, I cannot discern if this is just sugar deposits developing (they are very sweet, and I am told that as they dry you sometimes get sugar), or if this is small bugs.

**How can you tell the difference between bugs, which would make the dates not kosher, and other small, white things, like sugar deposits?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some useful rules of thumb:
If if moves, it's a bug.
If it has legs,it's a bug.
If it is asymmetrical, it's probably not a bug.

My guess is that it's just sugar.
In the future, you can keep the dates in the freezer if you're worried about them getting buggy.

-Rebbetzin HaQoton

Answer (score 2):

According to the Kof-K's [bug checking guide](http://www.kof-k.org/docs/CheckVegetablesForBugs.pdf) if webbing or seedy substance is seen, worms may be present. What you are describing does not sound like webbing or seedy substance so I would say it is not a problem.